# Bluebird promise: catching errors

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, promise, bluebird

I'm using the request module on Facebook's Graph API with the help of Bluebird's promise library. Tested the catch method by passing in a wrong secret key.

There are two issues here:
1. Why is the response in an array when I use promise?
2. Why is the clientError predicate is not being called at all?

```
var request = Promise.promisifyAll(require('request'));
var queryObj = {
    client_id: config.client_id,
    redirect_uri: config.redirect_uri,
    client_secret: config.wrong_client_secret,
    code: req.query.code
};

var reqObj = {
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token',
    qs: queryObj
};

request.getAsync(reqObj)
    .then(function (contents) {
        console.log('success ' + JSON.stringify(contents));
/*
Produces (simplified it for brevity)
[{"statusCode":400,"body":"{\"error\":{\"message\":\"Error validating client secret.\"}}"}]
*/

    }).catch(clientError, function(e) {
        console.log('error: ' + e);
    });

function clientError(contents) { // this is not called at all
    var statusCode = contents[0].statusCode;
    console.log('checking for error...' + statusCode);

    return statusCode >= 400 && statusCode < 500;
}

// without promise: 
var request = require('request');

request(reqObj, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
/* Response: (simplified it for brevity)
{"statusCode":400,"body":"{\"error\":{\"message\":\"Error validating client secret.\"}}"}
*/
        } else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Why is the response in an array when I use promise?

Because the `request` library is violating the callback contract by resolving the callback with multiple parameters. Bluebird has no choice but to wrap it in an array. You can easily `.get(0)` or `.get(1)` in order to access the specific property.

```
request.getAsync("...").get(0); // just the response
request.getAsync("...").spread(function(response, body){ // spread arguments
      // ...
});
```

> 2. Why is the clientError predicate is not being called at all?

Because the promise is not at an exception state, the previous promise *resolved* and the `then` callback ran.